# Why does the render not fill the screen outside of Play Mode?

Tags: unity, editors

I'm using Unity's Input System Package for the local Split-Screen feature for my game. When I play the game, the system works perfectly & divides the screen according to the player count (in this image, there's only one player so it's working):

[image: Play mode]

But the problem is that when the game is in Edit Mode, only half of the screen is rendered.

[image: Edit mode]

I understand that when the game is not played, actually there's no input to make it work correctly, but why it is half-divided? Is it possible to make it like normal (make it fill all the screen)?